# Automatically fill blanks in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How can I programmatically turn this:

```
@"This is any NSString with some blanks"
```

to this?

```
@"This+is+any+NSString+with+some+blanks"`
```

Comment: Check out stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString: withString:  on NSString.  And please try to google before asking questions here, this really was as simple as googling "NSString replace".

Comment: The answer below is correct. Sorry Stefan, I googled the wrong keywords. Maybe this question here helps anybody who also googles wrong ...

Comment: Google Directions API requires "+" instead of " " when requesting "Los+Angeles".

Comment: Yes, user input. I would like to use your code but it does not work properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSString *firstString = @"This is any NSString with some blanks";
NSString *secondString = [firstString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```